# How to deal with Arabic content (right to left) in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, multilingual

Currently working for multilingual site, where a page which is in English. Now when I am trying to translate this with Arabic then all the content into the content editor getting distorted,

Like in English we write content from left to right and in Arabic, right to left.

So do I need to do any customisation or there is any settings in sitecore?

Please help thanks

Comment: Can you share some screenshots, so that people can have a look at the exact problem you are facing. Also which sitecore version you are on?

Comment: It's confidential, but I'll share one dummy page after translation. Thanks

Comment: Using sitecore 8.0

Comment: Please try one of these
<style type="text/css"> body { direction:rtl; }</style>
or<body dir="rtl">

Comment: @PradeepGupta why don't you use RLT css file which will handle automatically RTL of content for your website

Comment: Is the problem in the Content Editor or the website itself?

Comment: On website and according to @Yogesh, can handle with CSS but issue is I'm not sure about content editor since all the content in arabic are alien for me, so is sitecore do this right to left change automatically on content editor? That's my doubt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the front-end website, this is unrelated to Sitecore. It can be handled with HTML and CSS.

In Content Editor, Sitecore handles this so you do not need to worry about it. I've worked on Arabic sites and the RTE popup automatically changes to RTL. The preview of RTL show LTR though but that's not a problem, it is still very much readable:
[image]
You can see the popup text is RTL but preview below it is LTR. But the characters order is still RTL so again don't worry about it.